# Is there any way to predict if the client's network will support WebRTC peer connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am creating a video conversation App and there's a device configuration check I run every time anyone wants to access the system. I could check browser getUserMedia, RTCPeerConnection, Also could check internet speed. But in many cases, RTCPeerConnection can still fail from that client's side because of some specific network restrictions/issues.

Is there any way to predict if a client's network will support video/audio streaming through RTCPeerConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of! Here are something things people have done, not perfect but you can explore from here.

Establish a DataChannel to another PeerConnection in the same tab, but run all communication through a TURN server. You can measure the quality of the connection without requiring any user interaction (allowing webcam access etc...)

You could also do some basic network mapping! Like determining your [NAT Type](https://webrtchacks.com/symmetric-nat/), you could get some hints at if you need a TURN server (or can do P2P) before the call. This will never get you a perfect answer, but at least some data!

I don't have a single good answer for you though, but these are some good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from the Accepted answer, I Initially created a Gist, later created a full fledge set of tools to determine if a certain webRTC feature works on not. this includes testing to see if RTCPeerConnection works, and also test for some other features as well.

Here's the Github link: https://github.com/theanam/webrtc-test-suite

Comment: This is really cool! Mind if I share on https://twitter.com/_pion ?

Comment: Would it be possible for `checkInternetSpeed` to use DataChannels? Since fetch is over TCP I think it could give different results. Happy to take the conversation over to GitHub instead :)

Comment: Sure, I'd love if you'd share. I have plans to write a new check for testing peer connection performance over data channel. Would love to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: Over DataChannels would be amazing! If you do that I would love to share. I am afraid that doing via fetch people will say 'This does not represent actual WebRTC quality'. If you can do DataChannel and have two PeerConnections using forced RTCIceTransportPolicy "relay"